# Merge Multiple Datasets with Identical Column Names in R While Attaching a Suffix to Each Column to Identify its Dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, inner-join, multiple-columns

I am trying to merge3 datasets, which are part of longitudinal study. The variable names are a identical across the waves of the study. What I want to accomplish is to attach a suffix to each variable name to indicate the dataset it belongs to while merging them. I have been able to do that in a roundabout way, but I am thinking there should be an easier way to accomplish that. Below is what I have done so far, just using some fictitious data to illustrate.

```
## step 1: create three dfs with identical variable names
df1 = data.frame('ID' = 1:10, 'V1' = sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T), 'v2' = sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T))
df2 = data.frame('ID' = 1:10, 'V1' = sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T), 'v2' = sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T))
df3 = data.frame('ID' = 1:10, 'V1' = sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T), 'v2' = sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T))

## step 2: function to rename all columns in a dataset
colsRename <- function(data, nn){
  
  nn = nn
  df = data %>% 
    rename_with(~ paste0(colnames(data), paste0('_'), nn)[which(colnames(data) == .x)], 
                .cols = colnames(data)) %>% 
    glimpse()
  
  return(df)
  
}

## call function to rename columns
w1 = colsRename(df1, 'W1') 
w2 = colsRename(df2, 'W2') 
w3 = colsRename(df3, 'W3') 

# merge the dataframes
dfMerge = merge(w1, w2, by.x = c("ID_W1"), by.y = c("ID_W2"), all = FALSE) %>% 
  merge(., w3, by.x = c("ID_W1"), by.y = c("ID_W3"), all = FALSE) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

The final output for the joined/merged dataframes will look something like below

```
   ID_W1 V1_W1 v2_W1 V1_W2 v2_W2 V1_W3 v2_W3
1      1     3     4     1     5     5     1
2      2     4     2     5     4     5     2
3      3     4     3     2     4     1     3
4      4     5     1     1     2     5     1
5      5     5     1     3     1     5     1
6      6     4     4     3     4     3     5
7      7     2     5     3     2     3     2
8      8     1     1     2     1     2     2
9      9     5     3     2     2     1     3
10    10     5     2     5     3     4     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the dataframe in a named list, rename the dataframes and use `reduce` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list(W1 = df1, W2 = df2, W3 = df3) %>%
  imap(function(x, y) x %>% rename_with(~paste(., y, sep = '_'), -ID)) %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = 'ID')

#   ID V1_W1 v2_W1 V1_W2 v2_W2 V1_W3 v2_W3
#1   1     1     1     5     2     5     5
#2   2     3     2     4     4     3     3
#3   3     4     3     5     4     1     2
#4   4     1     4     2     3     4     5
#5   5     3     5     1     1     1     5
#6   6     5     5     1     2     1     3
#7   7     4     3     3     1     3     2
#8   8     2     1     1     2     4     2
#9   9     5     2     5     4     1     2
#10 10     1     5     1     5     3     4
```

---

If there are more dataframe and you don't want to name them individually you can collect all the dataframes from the global environment using `mget`.

```
mget(ls(pattern = 'df\\d+')) %>%
  imap(function(x, y) x %>% rename_with(~paste(., y, sep = '_'), -ID)) %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = 'ID')
```

Answer (score 1):

In R base you may do

```
d_nm <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
L <- setNames(mget(d_nm), paste0('_W', seq(d_nm)))
Reduce(merge, Map(\(x, y) {names(x)[-1] <- paste0(names(x), y)[-1];x}, L, names(L)))
#    ID V1_W1 v2_W1 V1_W2 v2_W2 V1_W3 v2_W3
# 1   1     1     1     5     3     2     2
# 2   2     5     5     5     2     3     2
# 3   3     1     4     5     4     1     2
# 4   4     1     2     4     4     5     5
# 5   5     2     2     2     2     2     1
# 6   6     4     3     4     5     2     1
# 7   7     2     1     3     4     2     4
# 8   8     2     1     2     5     4     5
# 9   9     1     3     1     4     3     2
# 10 10     4     4     2     2     5     1
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(ID=1:10, V1=sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T), v2=sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=1:10, V1=sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T), v2=sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T))
df3 <- data.frame(ID=1:10, V1=sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T), v2=sample(x=1:5, size=10, replace=T))
```